# How do you find a local solution to $\mathbb{R}^3$ using $y=f(x)$, $z=g(x)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question I got is "Decide for which points of $\mathbb{R}^3$ the systems of equations $x+y+z=1$, $xy+yz+zx=4$ admits a local solution of the form $y=f(x)$, $z=g(x)$"

Our professor sort of explained this in class, but he was very vague. The textbook also does not explain it all too well. Sorry to bother y'all.

Comment: Do you know the implicit function theorem?

Comment: my professor said that it was not that important :/

Comment: $z=1-y-x$, substitute $z$ in the second equation and find $f(x)$

Comment: what would i do after that? I just got $4=y-y^2+x-xy-x^2$. This is not separable. :/

Comment: They never intersect, how there can be solution?